# How to get the url of a downloaded file

Tags: python, url

I have done a lot of research but I can find a way to get the url of a file already downloaded..
I want to get the urls to make a program to sort my files by them.
If anyone have an idea to get that or to make that in an other way im glade to hear it !
Sorry for my bad English !

Comment: If for example you downloaded a file with firefox, the downloaded file has no data or metadata containing the origin of the file, so for me this is not possible.

Comment: Ok i thought there is a way to store these files ... And I think it's not possible to modify chrome or Firefox to do that

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that it is in general possible, because data like these is not stored in file's metadata. If your script makes the download, you can save the link in code and then use it to sort your files, but if files are downloaded by the user it is impossible.

Comment: Ok ..  so there is no way to store data like these .. thank you !

Comment: If I helped you, please mark my answer